# Strange things happen after using std::strtod

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, strtod

Here's a small lambda function I use as an helper function in the code for my lexical analyzer:

```
auto buildnumber = [&line, &i] () -> Token* {
    Token* new_number = new Token(nullptr, number, line);

    char** after_number = nullptr;
    double* value = new double(std::strtod(i, after_number));

    printf("Value got: %f\n", *value);
    printf("Comparing it to 0\n");
    if (*value == 0.0) {
        printf("value was 0, comparing position to after number\n");
        if (i == *after_number) {
            printf("No number detected\n");
            delete value;
            delete new_number;
            return nullptr;
        }
    }

    printf("Value was different from 0, storing it in Token\n");
    new_number->value = (void*) value;
    printf("Advancing position\n");
    i = *after_number;
    printf("Returning\n");

    return new_number;
};
```

Here's a little background: `Token` is a class with an attribute `value` of type `void`, an attribute `line` of type `int`, and an attribute `type` of a custom enum `token_type`. In the first line I initialize a new one passing to its constructor a null pointer for the value (since we still have to create it), a value of the enum `token_type` (`number` because this token is of that type), and the current line we captured in the lambda.

`i` is a pointer of type `const char*` which points to the current characyer we're examining. When we call this lambda function, it's guaranteed that it will point to a printable character.

The `printf`s are for debugging purpose;

So what I am trying to do is: create a new `Token` of internal type `number`; ask `strtod` if we can build a number from the current position; then check if `strtod` returned a non-zero value, in which case we store that value in the new `Token`, advance the position of the character we're pointing to to the character directly after the number, and return the `Token`.

If `strtod` returned a zero value instead, we must doublecheck if the zero is because an actual 0 was found, or if instead no number could be built. So we check if the pointer to the character after the number points to the same character as the current positions: if it's true, it means that `strtok` didn't advance that pointer and it means no number at all was found (and we delete the allocated values and return a null pointer to signal that). Otherwise, it means that a 0 was found and so we store it, advance, and return.

The problem is, I get a Segfault error literally *every* time I try to deference `after_number`: that is, if I call `buildnumber` when `i` points to a string like `"111"`, I get a segfault after it prints `"Advancing position"`. And if I call it when `i` points to a string like `"+0.0"` or `"abc()"`, I get a segfault after it prints `"Value was 0, comparing position to after number"`.

Why is it? What happens to the pointer pointed to by `after_number`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `i == *after_number` causes undefined behaviour - dereferncing a null pointer

Comment: This ain't small.

Comment: @n.m well, if you take out the `printf` lines it's not too long. And you can also compress the two `if`s after "Comparing it to 0" in just one using an `&&`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've defined `after_number` as a pointer to a character pointer and then used that *directly,* when it doesn't actually point to anything useful.

The problem with that is that you're basically telling `strtod` not to actually *store* the end pointer (because you've provided `nullptr` as the address to store it in), then you go ahead and try to dereference it anyway - it will still be `nullptr` and you'll therefore get undefined behaviour.

The correct way to do it is as follows:

```
char *after_number;
double *value = new double(std::strtod(i, &after_number));
```

This actually *creates* a `char *` variable into which `strtod` can place the end pointer, and passes the address of it to `strtod`. Upon exit, `after_number` will hold the pointer to the end character that stopped the numeric evaluation (hopefully, that will be a pointer to the end of the actual string supplied, `*after_number == '\0'`.

Comment: I swear I used to do it this way but it threw some errors and I switched to the wrong way thinking that it would solve it. Now it's working anyway. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't that UB? If `strtod` checks if the given pointer is a `nullptr`, that means it has to read that variable and reading an indeterminate value (`char *after_number;`) is UB.

Comment: @Timo: `&after_number` is well-defined, it's the *address* of the pointer variable itself, and that variable exists on the stack here, so cannot be `nullptr`. It's true that `after_number` may be an arbitrary value but that's not relevant here.

Comment: ofc that makes sense. For some reason I was under the impression that the `after_number` pointer is checked for null and not the pointer to that variable. my bad